# Python 2.7 Installer on Mac OS 11.1 reads "software cannot be found? what is the work around for installing this on my mac?

Tags: python, macos

Python 2.7 package installer error on mac 11.1:

[image]

I tried installing python through package installer but could not get to work. Can someone suggest a work around for installing in terminal? ( please include what script to use) another work around is I have Virtual studio code. Can I download 2.7 in VS code as a work around? Thanks and let me know

Comment: Python 2.7 has been dead for many years.  You will discover that many features are no longer supported.  You really need to move to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Python in Terminal, first you have to install xcode-select if i guess right. After that install Brew if its not installed yet. Now you can run `brew install python@2.7.0`.

Otherwise you can look here: https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7

But i don´t now if this is working in your case, cause your mac-version probably don´t support 2.7 also 2. version are dead and lots of stuff don´t work anymore like already said.